# Firebase Sign Up functionality does not show user after authentication in firestore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

FIREBASE FILE

```js
REACT_APP_API_KEY = 8512cbd25e90468f2ba98f23ff1d476c

# FIREBASE KEYS
REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY = AIzaSyAbbQHhAgXJZ7T0M1MCugYLMELRQu8qRcU
REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN = netflix-clone-13127.firebaseapp.com
REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID =  netflix-clone-13127
REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET = netflix-clone-13127.appspot.com
REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER = 152205509894
REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_ID = 1:152205509894:web:691c5103c42a4db9840a87
```

The signup function to add an array after user signup

```js
  const signup = (email,password) => {
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth,email,password);
    setDoc(doc(db,'users',email),{
      savedShows:[]
    })
  }
```

After signup I can see the user

But I can see the user and array in firestore

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code. If this doesnt work it will atleast console log the actual error, and you can troubleshoot from there

```js
const signup = async (email,password) => {

  try{
    await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth,email,password);
    await setDoc(doc(db,'users',email),{
      savedShows:[]
    })
    }

  } catch(error){
    console.log(error)
  }
    
}
```

Comment: I’ve adapted your code since the `setDoc()` method is also asynchronous.